# A particle of charge $-e$ orbits a particle of charge $Ze$, what is its orbital frequency?

Tags: calculus, mathematical-physics

A point particle $P$ of charge $Ze$ is fixed at the origin in 3-dimensions, while a point particle $E$ of mass $m$ and charge $-e$ moves in the electric field of $P$.

I have the Newtonian equation of motion as
$$- \frac{Ze^2}{4 \pi \epsilon_{0}} \frac{\vec{r}}{r^3} = m \ddot{\vec{r}}$$ 
I derived this from Newton's law and Coulomb's law.

I then went on to show that the particle moves in a plane by showing it has a constant normal vector.

Can anyone help me find this if the orbit is circular about $P$ what it's orbital frequency is -in terms of the constants we have? I would be extremely grateful.

I have attempted this by  parameterizing the orbit, differentiating with respect to time and substituting into the equation of motion, however all I get are two unsolvable differentials equations.

Comment: Hint: $v=r\omega$ for circular orbits, and $a=v^2/r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already know that the orbit you're interested in, you don't need to *solve* differential equations as such. It doesn't take much thought to guess that the speed must be the same everywhere in a cirular orbit, bu symmetry -- so just postulate that the orbit has the standard parameterization of uniform circular motion:
$$ \vec r(t) = R\langle \cos(2\pi\nu t),\sin(2\pi\nu t)\rangle $$
for some $R$ and $\nu$.

Now compute $\ddot{\vec r}$ given this parameterization and plug into the equation of motion. What is left after some simplification is a system of two *non*-differential equations from which it should be easy to find the relation between $R$ and $\nu$ that make them true for all $t$.

Comment: Thank you! I was using parameters as the angle as a function of $t$, if you don't mind, why can we simply state the parameter as time?

Comment: I'm assuming that the circular motion is _uniform_, since it doesn't seem to make physical sense for symmetry reasons to have a non-uniform circular motion as a solution. Once we've decided to use uniform circular motion, the form of the parameterization is given up to a choice of radius, frequency (and initial angle which I'm here assuming for simplicity that we absorb into a choice of zero point for the time coordinate)

Comment: Ah I could kiss you! I've been trying for hours to solve non-linear differential equations..